# Probability of a white ball chosen from a bag if there are two bags.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I was reading Bayes' Theorem and I came across a question. The question was:

> What is the probability of picking a white ball from a bag, when there are two bags, **Bag A and Bag B**?
> Bag A contains $2$ white and $3$ red balls and Bag B contains $3$ white and $4$ red balls.

So, by Total Probability Theorem,

$$P(W)=P(A)\times P(W \mid A)+P(B)\times P(W \mid B).$$

From the given question, it is very easy to say that $P(W \mid A)$ is $2/5$. As in the **Bag A**, there are total $5$ balls and $2$ of them is white.

But I am unable to proof this mathematically that $P(W \mid A)$ is $2/5$.

My approach was $P(W \mid A)= P(W \cap A)/P(A).$

I think $P(W)$ and $P(A)$ are dependent events, as $P(W \mid A)$ and $P(W \mid B)$ are not same.

( I think probability of picking a white ball depends on the bag.)

So how can I prove that $P(W \mid A) =2/5$?

Comment: There is nothing to proof. You use the definition: $P(A|W)=\frac{\textrm{number of favorable outcomes}}{\textrm{total number of outcomes possible}}$

Comment: I'm not certain about vocabulary but think "dependence" is not a reflexive property.  Which marbles you pick is dependent on which bag you pick.  But which bag you pick is not dependent upon which marble you pick.  (Someone who recently took a class in prob can correct me).  Using Bayes to figure $P(M|N)$ is useful when $N$ is not independent or $M$ is not dependent on $N$ but if $N$ is independent and $M$ is dependent on $N$ then simple $\frac {favorable}{total}$ is the way to go, and Bayes is neither nesc. nor appropriate nor practical.

Comment: @fleablood The bag you pick *is* dependent on which (color) marble you pick.  [Dependence is not causality.]

Comment: Okay, I had the terminology wrong but that doesn't change that the probability of which bag (when the color of the marble is *not* given) is not affected by the marbles inside them.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier not to use Bayes thereom to *calculate* $P(W|A)$.  You are being confused by the notation of $|A$.  But that just says if your universe of options is pulling marbles from a bag that is $A$ then
$$P(W|A) = P(\text{pulling a white marble from bag A}) =\\ P(\text{pulling a white marble from a bag with 2 whites and 3 reds}) =\\ \frac {\text{favorable outcomes}}{\text{all outcomes}} = \frac 25$$.

If you want to view this in terms of Bayes Theorem then $P(W|A) =\frac {P(W\cap A)}{P(A)}$ which involves calculating $P(W\cap A)$ which... well, we are being circular but...

We have do the experiment $70$ times we have will pick bag $A$ $35$ times and $B$ $35$ times.  We will draw each of the marbles of bag $A$ $7$ times and the marbles of Bag $B$ $5$ times.  So $P(W\cap A) = \frac {7+7}{70} = \frac 1{5}$.

So $P(W|A) = \frac {P(W\cap A)}{P(A)} =\frac {\frac 1{5}}{\frac 12} =\frac 25$.

This *verifies* Bayes thereom but it is not the most natural way to set things up.

=======

It is useful to use Baye's Thereom to calculate $P(M|N)$ when $P(N)$ and $P(M\cap N)$ are easy to calculate, or in cases where Total Probability is not straightforward.  In cases were $P(M\cap N)$ or $P(N)$ are not easy to calculate, or where $P(M|N)$ is *itself* straightforward and *especially* when Total Probability *IS* straightforward, then... don't use it.

And in this case $P(W|A)= \frac 25$ and $P(W|B) = \frac 37$ is about as straightforward as it ever gets.

Comment: We have do the experiment 70 times we have will pick bag A 35 times and B 35 times. We will draw each of the marbles of bag A 7 times and the marbles of Bag B 5 times. So P(W∩A)=7+7/70=1/5.............I have not understood this part, can you please explain

Comment: Bag A has five marbles and bag B has 7 marbles and there are 2 bags.   We want to do the experiment enough times so that every marble is picked a whole number of times and every marble is picked a representative number of times.  To pick every marble of Bag A we must pick bag A a multiple of $5$ times.  But we pick bag A the times so we must do it of $10$ bags. To pick every marble of bag B we must pick bag $B$ a multiples of $7$ times. As we pick bag B half the times we must do it a multiple of $14$ times.  So the number of times we do this must be a multiple of both $10$ and $14$.  i.e. $70$

Comment: Why this?? P(W∩A)=7+7/70=1/5 ??

Comment: There are two white marbles in bag A.  And out of the $70$ times you you do the experiment you pick each of those marbles $7$ times.  So the probability that you pick a white marble from bag A is $\frac {7+7}{70}=\frac15$.  ... Again I need to emphasis this is *only* for illustrating Bayes Theory holds true.  As a practical calculation of $P(W\cap A)$ this is a *terrible* way to do it.  The *better* way is simple to state $P(W\cap A)=P(W|A)\cdot P(A) = \frac 25\cdot \frac 12 = \frac 15$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for probability of drawing white given A,
don't use P(W\A), the correct symbol is $P(W|A)$

And P(W|A) is simply the ratio of white balls to total balls in $A$, so there is nothing to prove here.

So, by Total Probability Theorem,

$P(W)=P(A)*P(W|A)+P(B)*P(W|B) = \Large\frac12\frac25 + \frac12\frac37$

---

### ADDED

Bayes' Rule would be needed if you has been asked, say, $P(A|W)$

$P(A|W) = \dfrac{P(A)*P(W|A)}{P(A)*P(W|A)+ P(B)*P(W|B)}$

Answer (score 0):

I used a tree diagram.
You draw all the options and their respective probabilities, then you can multiply them to get the probability for the event at the bottom of the tree.
Here, getting White from Bag A would be $2/10$ since you first have a chance of $1/2$ of picking Bag A and then also have to get White which is $2/5$. Since $1/2 \times 2/5$ is $2/10$ that's the result.
Getting White out of Bag B has a different chance because there are different Balls in each bag, even though the chance for each bag is the same. Here getting white out of Bag B would be $3/14$ as shown in the picture below:

$\qquad\quad\qquad$[image: pic]

Comment: It is not good to put a screenshot of the original question in your answer. The question is subject to editing at any time. In fact, this has already happened. Welcome to Math Stack.